# Is there UITextContentType for currency?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uitextfield, textfield

If not, is it possible to create one?
In both `SwiftUI` and `UIKit` `UITextInputTraits` define features for keyboard input to a text object. There are several predefined constants, but it seems that currency is not covered.
The vary naive implementation without such trait could look as follows:

```
TextField("", value: $receivedCash, format: .currency(code: order.currency))
     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
```

But wouldn't it be more natural to have UITextInputTrait for currency?

Comment: https://github.com/Flight-School/Money

Comment: Really interesting repo, @MaziarSaadatfar. Maybe I'll try it, thanks.